# Cannot pass data between classes

Tags: java, android, basic4android

I have an activity which creates a unique ID and then passes the String to a service, the problem I am having is that the app force-closes every time I try passing the data from the activity to the service.

Normally when I am programming java applications I just use getter and setter methods to pass data between classes, so does anyone have an idea why this problem is occurring?

```
public void setId(String mydeviceId){

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    final String DeviceId, SerialNum, androidId;
    DeviceId = tm.getDeviceId();
    SerialNum = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    androidId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)DeviceId.hashCode() << 32) | SerialNum.hashCode());
    mydeviceId = deviceUuid.toString(); 
    this.mydeviceId = mydeviceId;   

    }


    public String getId(){

        return mydeviceId;

    }
```

Comment: Pass between classes means activities? If so, you need to use Intent bundle. Get/set wont work between activities.

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat, the source where the exception was raised, and identify the line number in the source where the exception was raised.

Comment: I was getting a null pointer exception this must of been down to the point that @thinksteep made that I need to use an Intent bundle, so I will take a look in to how pass data using intent bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass between classes means activities? If so, you need to use Intent bundle. Get/set wont work between activities. Here is an example [how to pass data between activities.](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/)

Comment: cheers for that thinksteep, I was wondering would I also have to this when passing data from a service to a java class ?

Comment: No, you cannot do this with services. Refer to my answer on this.

Comment: Here is SO discussion on service to activity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747448/android-passing-data-between-service-and-activity.   By the way, one small suggestion, in Android terms (not official, but understanding purpose) if you are discussing about activity, its better not call as class(which may represent helper class/inner class).

Answer (score 1):

In order to communicate with your service, allow your Activity to `bind` with it. Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) guide. Its is the recommended way.

Alternatively, you may broadcast your desired values to communicate between Service and/or Activity. For more info, refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)